# Prove that $G(n) = \sum_{d|n} \frac{n}{d}\tau(d)$ is multiplicative.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function

I don't know how to prove this because it seems to me that $f(d)=\frac{n}{d}\tau(d)$ is not multiplicative.

Comment: Do you know about Dirichlet convolutions of (multiplicative) functions?

Answer (score 1):

The (Dirichlet) convolution of two multiplicative functions is multiplicative, i.e.
$$
f(n)=\sum_{d|n}g(n/d)h(d)
$$
is multiplicative if $g$, $h$ are.  Both $g(n)=n$ and $\tau(n)=\sum_{d|n}1$ (if that's what you mean by $\tau$) are multiplicative, so their convolution is as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do have a related question. Doesn't the multiplicativeness of $G(n) = \sum_{d|n} \frac{n}{d}\tau(d)$ imply that $f(d)=\frac{n}{d}\tau(d)$ is multiplicative?

Comment: @BrettLane I'm not sure what you mean.  Your comment $f$ has $f(ab)=\frac{n}{ab}\tau(ab)=\frac{1}{n}\frac{n}{a}\frac{n}{b}\tau(a)\tau(b)=\frac{1}{n}f(a)f(b)$, so no it's not multiplicative, unless $n=1$.  I think what you might mean is that a product of multiplicative functions is multiplicative:  $(f\cdot g)(ab)=f(ab)g(ab)=f(a)g(a)f(b)g(b)=(f\cdot g)(a)(f\cdot g)(b)$.

Comment: In my textbook ('Elementary Number Theory by David M. Burton) there's a theorem that states that if $F$ is a multiplicative function and $F(n)=\sum_{d|n}f(d)$, then $f$ is also multiplicative. Though I'm beginning to suspect that's an oversimplification.